# How to make network endpoint groups disappear automatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

In GCP, I have a GKE with a workload configured. My service definition has the following annotation which automatically creates the network endpoint groups for me:

```
cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{"name": "app2-service-80-neg"}}}'
```

I can then attach this to a backend load balancer service and all works well. However, shouldn't these network endpoint groups disappear if I delete the underlying service/deployment/pods? They seem to stick around after I delete everything at the kubernetes level which causes issues for my terraform because I run a terraform destroy regularly and it can't delete everything since these objects are still kicking around preventing me from deleting my VPC.

Comment: I ended up using terraform on destroy provisioners to solve this problem. Since the garbage collection doesn't happen quickly enough for it to work through terraform. This solved my issue perfectly. 


  `provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups delete app2-service-80-neg --zone=us-east1-c --quiet"
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vishal Bulbule mentioned NEG has to be deleted separately.
As per this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networkEndpointGroups/delete)

> Note that the NEG cannot be deleted if there are backend services referencing it.

So,

- When a GKE service is deleted, the associated NEG will not be
  garbage collected if the NEG is still referenced by a backend
  service.
- Dereference the NEG from the backend service to allow NEG deletion.
- When a cluster is deleted, standalone NEGs are not deleted automatically and need to be deleted manually.
  Use [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networkEndpointGroups/delete#http-request) Http request to delete the NEG or else refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/network-endpoint-groups/delete) to help in deleting it manually.

You can also use below to delete a network endpoint group named my-neg:

```
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups delete my-neg --zone=us central1-a
```

Answer (score 2):

Backend service for load balancer and actual NEG are two separate resources. NEG has to be deleted separately. This will happen even if you add VM Instances IP to NEG .